# Hortonworks HDP 2.1 rename cluster

Tags: rename, hortonworks-data-platform, falcon

How to rename the cluster in hdp 2.1?
There is a ui option to change in hdp 2.2 but I am unable to find any option and any configuration to rename the cluster in hdp 2.1.I need to rename it because I gave the cluster name with underscore but while using falcon it does not allowed the cluster name with underscore.